# Be a little more flexible with adding quotes in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, blockquote

I'd like chat to support the following scenarios (so that my blood pressure will go down)

```
>Text butts up directly next to the greater than symbol

@jerky >Quote comes after a user reference (drop the quote to the next line)

@jerky > Oh and this too.  That space is significant!
```

Comment: +1 for the last one.  I also think it should work for replies - "`:12345> I loves me some chat`".  For the other two, I think we should be able to get the spaces right without developer assistance ;-)

Comment: @jadarnel27: I can never remember that you *have have have* to have a space in there.  For some reason.  Which I think is arbitrary.

Comment: Reply-quoting is [now possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171474/)

Answer (score 6):

If *these* ***awesome*** little tweaks are worth doing, I'd like to see something else done at the same time:

> Multi
>
> Line
>
> Quotes

Those are the ones that I actually *want* to visually separate, after all. For a single line, I could just use... "quotation marks".