# Make quotes work when I reply

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Sometimes I like to reply to people. Sometimes I like to quote things. This is all fine. However, sometimes I like to do *both these things at once*, which is when the trouble starts:

[image]

Most things format correctly when I'm replying, so why don't quotes?

Comment: Also multiline quotes should work

Comment: @BenBrocka Oh God yes, please fix this too!

Comment: @fredley I thought the conventional way to quote someone was to surround quote with apostrophes...

Comment: @Gabe In chat (as in posts), if you prefix your comment with `> ` it will show up in a special 'quote' format. This is what I'm referring to here.

Comment: >and this should also be treated as a quote, damnit.

Comment: Next you're going to want markdown to work in multiline messages, like some kind of madman

Comment: @MichaelMrozek careful now; that's just crazy talk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fine, fine... have it your way... explicit replies that are quotes now omit the `@Whoever`, which means they render as quotes. So they behave like images, etc:

[image]

<s>Part of this ties into: *what do we do for multiple lines*...</s>

[image]

We can't leave the bar on the left - that would suggest you were quoting something that included the `@BenBrocka`. If we put the bar over to the right (not even thinking about how crazy the layout would be for that), we end up cutting the horizontal space to pieces.

A pragmatic option would be to just handle the `@BenBrocka` *separate to* the quoting...

Comment: Isn't handling the `@BenBrock` separate for other things? If I reply with an image link, the image will onebox and the `@BenBrock` disappear (just the arrow is left). Why not do this?

Comment: @fredley ok, ok - let me try something locally...

Comment: @casperOne frankly, no; that would not have been trivial. Searching for `@foo` already has examples where it won't work in that way - various oneboxes will omit that. The system knows what are replies, and to who, though.

Comment: A little more spacing between the reply arrow and the vertical line please...